# Jump to frame for Flash fallback in mediaelements.js

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is it possible to jump time frame while using the Flash fallback? Here is my example. This works for the HTML5 but not the Flash version.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

MediaElement('player1', {success: function(me) {

    me.play();

    me.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Math.round(me.currentTime);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('pp')['onclick'] = function() {
        if (me.paused)
            me.play();
        else
            me.pause();
    };

    $('body').on('click', '#jumpTo', function(){

        console.log('clicked');

        var jumpTo = 15;
        me.currentTime = jumpTo;
        me.play();

        return false;
    });


}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `setCurrentTime()` function. The `currentTime` property can only be used as a getter.

Do it like this:

```
me.setCurrentTime(jumpTo); //Time in seconds
```

It is described in the [API section](http://mediaelementjs.com/#api) of the project web site where you also find all other API calls.